# Stored procedure DateTime 'Parameter not found in the collection' error

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a c# .Net program that utilizes the MySQL.Data library to connect to my MySQL database hosted in AWS. I have a stored procedure called "get_dates" in my database that is defined as follows:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user_name`@`%` PROCEDURE `get_dates`(IN _identifier VARCHAR(20), OUT activation_date DATETIME, OUT deactivation_date DATETIME)
BEGIN 
SELECT ifnull(ACTIVATION_DATE, "2000-01-01 12:00:00") INTO activation_date FROM table_name WHERE ID = _identifier;
SELECT ifnull(DEACTIVATION_DATE, "2000-01-01 12:00:00") INTO deactivation_date FROM table_name WHERE ID = _identifier;
END
```

From my program I call the stored procedure in this manner:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand getDatesCommand = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();
getDatesCommand.Connection = connection.connection.Connection;
getDatesCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
getDatesCommand.CommandText = "get_dates";
getDatesCommand.Parameters.Add("@_identifier", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.VarChar);
getDatesCommand.Parameters["@_identifier"].Value = identifierVar;
getDatesCommand.Parameters.Add("@activation_date", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.DateTime);
getDatesCommand.Parameters["@activation_date"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
getDatesCommand.Parameters.Add("@deactivation_date", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.DateTime);
getDatesCommand.Parameters["@deactivation_date"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
getDatesCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

DateTime activation_date = (DateTime)getDatesCommand.Parameters[@"activation_date"].Value;
DateTime deactivation_date = (DateTime)getDatesCommand.Parameters[@"deactivation_date"].Value;
getDatesCommand.Dispose();
```

I am receiving a System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter 'activation_date' not found in the collection.' exception at the line

```
DateTime activation_date = (DateTime)getDatesCommand.Parameters[@"activation_date"].Value;
```

I honestly have no idea. any help would be appreciated. I would also like to continue to use DateTime variables and not like to reformat my tables to use Varchars instead.

Comment: I don't use MySql so this is just a guess, but you have assigned your parameters with the `@` symbol but you are pulling them back out of the command without it. What happens if you `...Parameters["@activation_date"].Value;` ?

Comment: @Crowcoder if you post an answer, I can mark it as correct to give you the credit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Crowcoder helped me figure it out. I just missed typed my `@` in front of my double-quote instead of inside it. Thanks for the help